# Sublime Text How to Customize Reindent?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there any option to change the setting of 'reindent', the default package doesn't give much information regarding reindent customization?

I'd like to format the following block

```
.example{asd:qweweq; qwrqr:afakr;}
```

into

```
.example {
  asd   : qweweq;
  qwrqr : afakr;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alignment](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) seems to do part of what you're looking for.

Comment: Hah, glad I could help :)

Comment: I wish it has an auto-detect-colon feature, but the current feature safes plenty time already than doing manually.

Comment: lol found the way to solve that... - "alignment_space_chars": ["=", ':'],